# Что он сделал(,) было очень плохо сделано

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, нужны ли те запятые в следующих предложениях?

1. Что он сделал(,) было очень плохо сделано.
2. Кто постучал в дверь(,) был Пётр.
3. Кто всё время думает о своих мечт(,) обычно ничего не делает-таки.

Comment: Второе некорректно.

Comment: А что с мечтами? Почему урезаны до мечт?

Comment: Во втором примере "тем" опущено, а его нельзя опускать из-за того, что оно в падеже, поэтому некорректно.

Answer (score 0):

В примерах опущено подлежащее, которым они могли бы открываться: существительным или местоимением-существительным *тот*, *та*, *то*.

Как ука­зы­ва­ю­щее на при­знак пред­ме­та, хотя бы его род, в кон­тек­сте оно может упо­треб­лять­ся само­сто­я­тель­но без суще­стви­тель­но­го. Игнорировать неприсутствие члена предложения неправильно, и запятые надо ставить.

*То, что он сделал, было очень плохо сделано; Тот, кто постучал в дверь, был Пётр; Та, кто всё время думает, обычно ничего не делает.*

Comment: Я специально их опустил. Я спрашиваю насчёт того, нужна ли запятая в предложении с опущенными членами.

Comment: «Игнорировать неприсутствие члена предложения неправильно, и **запятые надо ставить**».