# О коммуникативной оценке предложений при выборе знаков препинания

Tags: грамматика

**Коммуникативность** — это умение верно передавать информацию, свои мысли. Это способность формулировать высказывания таким образом, что весь вкладываемый смысл полностью понимается собеседником. https://infourok.ru/statya-chto-takoe-kommunikativnost-1494707.html

Существует мнение, что правильность построения предложения и выбор в нем нужных знаков препинания часто зависит от того, **кому, что и когда мы говорим.**

Это действительно так и можно ли это увидеть **на конкретных примерах**?

Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147136/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Коммуникативность речи** — это очень важно. В современной **лингвистике** предложение рассматривается:

(1) как **единица языка** с определенной структурой (собственно предложение);  оно как бы ничье, не имеет автора и никому не адресовано;

(2) как **единица речи** (предложение как конкретное высказывание при общении);  оно подразумевает автора, обращено к собеседнику, используется в определенных условиях  и имеет целевую направленность.

Материал взят **из монографии**: В.И. Казарина "Простое предложение в аспекте структурно-семантического подхода."

Рассмотрим  [примеры из недавнего вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474458/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE) и **дадим им оценку**. На первый взгляд они кажутся некорректными  по стилю и грамматике, но, может быть, и для них **можно подобрать** подходящую ситуацию при общении?

**Пример 1**

— Все-таки он кое-что **сдЕлал** полезного…

— Что он сделал, было очень **плОхо** сделано.

**Пример 2**

— **Ты знАешь**, кто там был?

— Их было несколько человек. Кто **постучАл в дверь**, был Пётр.

**Пример 3**

— Он много мечтает, что в этом **плохОго**?

— Кто всё время думает о своих мечтах, обычно ничего таки **не дЕлает**.

Во всех предложениях поставлены **запятые** (это сложные предложения разного вида). Я бы не стала использовать другие знаки, так как логически выделено **одно** из простых предложений в составе сложного (к нему обращено **основное внимание** собеседников), а второе предложение выглядит по значимости как "сопутствующее".

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147137/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Дорогие участники форума, **спасибо вам** за такое увлекательное обсуждение темы!

А это **пародия-шутка** по поводу одной из «неправильных» фраз.

Итак, общество (community) против  общения (communication)? Другими словами, не признает того, что в нашей речи присутствует **коммуникативная поправка.**

Ну что ж, значит, общественность еще  не готова к тому, чтобы увидеть себя **в зеркале общения.** Кажется, мы не слышим сами себя, но думаем, что всегда говорим правильно.  И уж точно никогда не скажем: ***Кто постучАл в дверь, был Пётр.*** Кривая, неправильная фраза!  А скажем так: «***Их было несколько человек.  Стучал в дверь Пётр***".  Вот это хорошо, благозвучно, это – культура речи!

*А теперь представьте, что вы (двое, трое) прячетесь в темном подвале. Главное – не выдать себя. Там, за дверью, люди. Кто они, враги или друзья?  Стук в дверь:  «Откройте!» Голос кажется знакомым. А теперь вроде бы уходят! Переговариваться можно очень тихо, сдавленным шепотом.*

И вот в такой ситуации вы спокойно говорите: «*Стучал в  дверь Петр»*. Эта фраза даже не ответ на заданный вопрос. **Полная информация** такая:  «Там не один человек, их несколько. Я узнал по голосу только одного: это Петр, вы его тоже знаете»…  И вот кривая по форме фраза по содержанию **ближе к истине**, чем правильная и литературная)).

Или другой вариант: представьте, что вы пишете **роман с таким сюжетом**. Разве эта вялая, безжизненная речь, построенная по всем правилам грамматики, может понравиться вашим читателям!

**P.S.** Вообще говоря, **записывать** разговорную речь намного труднее, чем литературную. И еще один **парадокс**: чтобы составить неправильную по грамматике фразу, надо очень хорошо **знать грамматику**. (Ну или заняться медитацией, войти в образ и писать по интуиции.) Мастерство писателя (или вообще Мастера) – в умении обозначить **нюансы, детали, штрихи** (в том числе и в речевой практике).

**Грамматическая справка**  (из учебника «Синтаксис современного русского языка»)

Это СПП с  придаточным  местоименно-соотносительным, например: Тот, кто выполнил все задания, получил  «пять». Местоименная пара: тот – кто. В литературной речи местоимение «***тот***» обязательно, но в **разговорном** стиле оно может **опускаться:** Кто выполнил все задания, получил «пять».

Сравнить: *Тот, кто постучал в дверь, был Пётр. **Кто постучал в дверь, был Петр*.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147172/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ (по комментариям)

**1. Зачем тут нужен латинизм, если есть русские слова.**

Посмотрим в словарь: **КОММУНИКАЦИЯ**, [лат. communicatio – сообщение] **2. Лингв.** Сообщение или передача средствами языка содержания высказывания. Коммуникативная функция языка.

Если слово есть в толковом словаре, значит, оно уже закрепилось в языке.
Слов с этим латинским корнем у нас много.

**ОБЩЕНИЕ.**  Взаимные отношения, деловая или дружественная связь. **СООБЩЕНИЕ.** 2. То, что сообщается; известие; сведения, информация, сообщаемые, излагаемые кем-л..

Беседа? Нет, это уже не лингвистический термин. **БЕСЕДА**. 1. Разговор, официально-деловой или задушевный.  2. Сообщение на какую-л. тему, в форме обмена мнениями, обсуждения вопросов. Этимология слова: https://dzen.ru/a/YjY9svBVPzDprkza

**2. Как я понимаю коммуникативную функцию языка**

В лингвистике мы рассматриваем скорее **«СО-ОБЩЕНИЕ»,** то есть совместное/взаимное общение, при котором **средствами языка передается информация** (от одного объекта другому объекту). Мы пользуемся **готовыми языковыми формами**, но в своих целях общения. **Мы всегда обращаемся к кому-то** – перед нами постоянно этот воображаемый или реальный собеседник.

**Любое наше слово и даже любая мысль** – это обращение. В речи постоянно присутствует адресат и всегда есть цель.

Грамматика предлагает нам определённые **языковые модели** как нечто **абстрактное**, а мы наполняем их **конкретным** содержанием. Можно сравнить с математикой: языковая модель предложения – это **скалярная** (ненаправленная) величина, а высказывание в речи – величина **векторная**.

**3.  О двух значениях слова «коммуникация»**

**КОММУНИКАЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. communicatio - сообщение] **1. Спец.** **Путь сообщения, связь одного места с другим.** Водные коммуникации. Перерезать коммуникации противника. Массовая к. (способ сообщения какой-л. информации всем или многим с помощью технических средств). Средства массовой коммуникации (о газетах, радио, телевидении **2. Лингв**. **Сообщение или передача средствами языка содержания высказывания.** Акт коммуникации. <Коммуникативный, -ая, -ое (2 зн.). К-ая функция языка. Коммуникационный, -ая, -ое (1 зн.). К-ые линии.

**Коммуникация в лингвистике** – это не коммуникация в общем понимании (по первому  словарному  значению)  по схеме «отдал, принял, всё, дал обратную связь, в очень толерантной форме, чтобы не создать конфликта». В лингвистике мы используем **абстрактное понимание этого термина**,  даже прилагательные разные: **коммуникативная** связь в лингвистике и  **коммуникационные** линии связи в обычном смысле.

**Цитата:** «*Коммуникация – это правильное изложение общеизвестных истин или указание на них в рамках общеизвестных правил. То есть с помощью коммуникации нельзя сказать ничего того, что человек уже не знает»*.

Это опять же не лингвистическое понимание термина, а оценка содержания информации, то есть коммуникация в первом словарном значении

**4. О языке**

Насколько **совершенны**  языковые средства  и насколько мы их **освоили** – это уже другая тема, а именно **точность передачи информации**. Непосредственно к коммуникативной функции  языка это не имеет отношения. Здесь мы уже говорим о понятиях и словах для их обозначения и т.д.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147171/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.